# Is it possible to label saved places on Google maps?

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to choose an address and leave a labeled marker there?

I noticed that you can save places using stars, but I would like to label them. Like, save an address and label it "Friend's house" or something.

Answer (score 2):

You totally can! It's admittedly difficult to find (or at least it was for me).

1. Navigate to [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps) and make sure you're signed in (note: not sure if this works on a mobile device).
2. Click on the little "hamburger menu" inside the address search bar (in the upper left hand corner of the map, at least on my browser).
3. Click on "My Maps"

You can now create your own map, add addresses (as markers), assign custom labels to the markers, and then style the markers according to your labels, if you so choose.

For instance, you could have a different color or a different shape marker depending on whether the pointer was a "friend's house" or a "historical landmark" or anything else you can imagine.

I made this map for a friend who was new to the San Francisco Bay Area, to help her figure out which cities were considered what area, approximate drive times, etc., [Bay Area Map with Custom Labels](https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zsi1uAlx79GA.kgMasdIbHxjg&usp=sharing).

Answer (score -2):

You can edit it in Google Bookmarks (https://www.google.com/bookmarks/)

Comment: If you add how to do this that would be more helpful.